# uri scheme for Microsoft Sharepoint

Tags: ios, url-scheme

How can i find the uri scheme for Microsoft SharePoint app on ios.
I need to open the app from my application.

I am tryying to launch another application from my application using the URI schemes.

Comment: [Office URI Schemes](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/dn906146.aspx)

Answer (score 3):

It's actually pretty simple.  If you just want to launch sharepoint, you can do the below:

```
ms-sharepoint://a
```

This link does not list the sharepoint uri, but I tested it and it works:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/dn906146.aspx

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the answer.
But if I want it directly to sites can I do that? I need a schema.
e.g. https://company.sharepoint.com/sites/collection/News
I test below, 
ms-sharepoint://https://company.sharepoint.com/sites/collection/News
ms-sharepoint://company.sharepoint.com/sites/collection/News
It above not work, but switch to SharePoint Application Ok
If you have a solution, thank you very much.

Comment: @bamossza since their docs don't have of the uri schemas listed for sharepoint, it might not be possible.

Answer (score 0):

This is the correct format :

```
Launch("ms-sharepoint://webDeepLink";"url";"https://xxx.sharepoint.com/(...)")
```

or direct link

```
ms-sharepoint://webDeepLink?url=https://xxx.sharepoint.com/(...)
```

Have to search in Sharepoint app source code ...